# How to change stylesheet if the user is on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I know how to return a boolean for whether the user is on mobile or not, but how can I use JavaScript to use that and change the stylesheet (and maybe HTML ) document that it uses?

Comment: You cannot undo stylesheet with javascript, once it is loaded from html. Though you can modify computed css to what is desired with js but that is painful way to do it. Recommended way is using media queries, @Stevangelista has posted an example of it.

Answer (score 5):

There's no need to use JS for this - you can use media queries to load a specific CSS file based on device type, screen orientation, screen resolution, etc.

You can find plenty of examples and explanations here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Some examples therein:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 800px)" href="LargeScreen.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 800px), handheld and (orientation: portarit)" href="Mobile.css" />
```

And a jsFiddle demo - you can see the `div` change color based on viewport size:
https://jsfiddle.net/4w13k9jp/

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #box {
    background-color:red
  }
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  #box {
    background-color:blue
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change color with css media querys:

```css
#one {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    width:30%;
    height:100px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    #one {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
```

you could also remove some elements

```js
function DeleteForId(id) {
    var elemento = document.getElementById(id);
    return elemento.parentNode.removeChild(elemento);
}




DeleteForId("segundoDiv");
```

```css
#primerDiv{
background:red;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
}
 #segundoDiv{
background:blue;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
}
.tercerDiv{
background:orange;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="primerDiv"></div>
<div id="segundoDiv"><img src="http://cdn01.ib.infobae.com/adjuntos/162/imagenes/014/014/0014014674.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"></div>

<div class="tercerDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use javascript to  change stylesheet on the fly

```
<head>
    <link id="style" rel=stylesheet href="large.css">

</head>






    function changeStyle(){
        if(window.innerWidth<900){
            document.getElementById("style").setAttribute("href","mobile.css");

       }else if((window.innerWidth)>900 &&(window.innerWidth)<1200){
         document.getElementById("style").setAttribute("href","medium.css");   
       }
        else 
              document.getElementById("style").setAttribute("href","large.css"); 
    }  
    window.onresize=changeStyle;
   changeStyle();
```